When is $X_n \sim N(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$ uniformly integrable?
I'm considering solving the question by using the definition.
i) $\ \sup_\limits{n \geq 1}E \vert X_n \vert<\infty $
ii)$\ \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0\,:\,\forall A\in \mathbb{F},P(A)<\delta \implies \sup_\limits{n\geq 1}E \vert X_n \vert\mathbb{1}_A<\infty$
Here is my attempt for the second condition. Since $X_n=\mu_n+\sigma_nZ$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$:
\begin{align} \sup_\limits{n\geq 1}E|Xn|\mathbb{1}_A &
= \sup\limits_{n\geq 1}E|\mu_n|\mathbb{1}_A+\sigma_nZ|\mathbb{1}_A \\ &
=\sup_\limits{n\geq 1}E|\mu_n|\mathbb{1}_A+\sup_{n\geq 1}\sigma_nE|Z|\mathbb{1}_A \\ &
=\sup_\limits{n\geq 1}|\mu_n|P(A)+\sup_{n\geq 1}\sigma_nE|Z|\mathbb{1}_A \end{align}
Now since $Z$ is u.i., let $E|Z|\mathbb{1}_A \leq \varepsilon \sup_\limits{n\geq 1} \sigma_n$ and $P(A)<\delta $ which is arbitraily small so $$\sup\limits_{n\geq 1}|\mu_n|P(A) \longrightarrow 0$$
Then $\sup_\limits{n\geq 1}E|X_n|\mathbb{1}_A< \varepsilon$. Am I thinking the right way?

It's not apparent what your question is. As a start, notice that if both $(\mu_n)$ and $(\sigma_n)$ are bounded sequences, then $(X_n)$ is u.i. — consider $E(X_n^2)$.

Quite easy to se that the sequence is uniformly integrable iff $(\mu_n)$ and $(\sigma_n)$ are bounded.

Here's the proof of @geetha290krm's comment:

The collection $\{X_n: n \ge 1\}$ where $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$ is UI iff $(\mu_n), (\sigma_n)$ are bounded sequences.

"$\Longrightarrow$" Assume $\{X_n: n \ge 1\}$ is UI. Since $\vert \mu_n \vert = \vert \mathbb{E}(X_n) \vert \le \mathbb{E}\vert X_n \vert$. Thus, $\sup_n \vert \mu_n \vert \le \sup_n \mathbb{E} \vert X_n \vert < \infty$, i.e $(\mu_n)$ is bounded. Moreover, $\mathbb{E}\vert X_n \vert = \mathbb{E}\vert \mu_n + \sigma_n Z \vert$, where  $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, thus,
$$
    \begin{align*}
    \sigma_n \mathbb{E}\vert Z \vert &= \mathbb{E}\vert \mu_n + \sigma_n Z - \mu_n \vert\\
 &\le \mathbb{E} \vert \mu_n + \sigma_n Z \vert + \vert\mu_n \vert = \mathbb{E} \vert X_n \vert + \vert\mu_n\vert\\ &\le \sup_n \mathbb{E} \vert X_n \vert + \sup_n \vert \mu_n \vert < \infty
    \end{align*}
$$
which implies $(\sigma_n)$ is also bounded.
"$\Longleftarrow$" Assume $(\mu_n), (\sigma_n)$ are bounded sequences. Then, choosing convex function $f(x) = x^2$, which is increasing on $\mathbb{R}_+$, we have $\sup_n \mathbb{E}(f(\vert X_n \vert)) = \sup_n \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) = \sup_n (\mu_n^2 + \sigma_n^2) < \infty$. Thus, $\{X_n: n \ge 1\}$ is UI.

This is very clear. Thank you!
